# Callable argument has unused name

Tags: typescript, signature, callable-object

Is there any reason the parameter name inside a function type exists?

```js
function greeter(fn: (a: string) => void) {
  fn("Hello, World");
}
```

In the above example (from [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-type-expressions)) why is `a` needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Note" in [the documentation you linked](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-type-expressions) makes the primary point:

> Note that the parameter name is required. The function type `(string) => void` means “a function with a parameter named `string` of type `any`“!

Fundamentally, the name is needed because the syntax needs an identifier or similar to apply the type annotation to.¹

It also has the handy effect of providing a hint your IDE can show you later when you're trying to remember what the argument is. (That's not really important in the example you quoted where the signature is *right there*, but 20 lines further down, it's handy.)

But primarily: Because the syntax requires it.

---

¹ **Technically**, you could have an empty destructuring pattern like `({}: string) => void`, but don't do that. :-) It would be misleading to the reader, and problematic if the argument is allowed to be `null` or `undefined` (since you can't destructure those).